# adding dynamicly TitledPanes to Accordion

Tags: java, swing, javafx, accordion

So I'm creating a program that gets the swagger doc.json, extracts all the REST Apis then shows them in an Accordion: the problem is that the Accordion won't work for me because `TitledPanes` are added dynamically: i.e: for each Rest API endpoint extracted out of the `JSON` file a new `TitledPane` will show up.

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import io.swagger.models.HttpMethod;
import io.swagger.models.Operation;
import io.swagger.models.Path;
import io.swagger.models.Response;
import io.swagger.models.Swagger;
import io.swagger.models.parameters.Parameter;
import io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GroupOfTitledPane extends Application {
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField t1;
    JButton btn;
    int i;
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(400,250);
        frame. setLocation(500,300);
        t1=new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(60,40,270,30);
        frame.add(t1);
        btn=new JButton("SUBMIT");
        btn.setBounds(140,90,100,30);
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource()==btn)
                {
                    String input=t1.getText();
                    if(input.isEmpty() || input.equals(" "))
                    {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Veuillez saisir l'adresse de l'URL");
                    }
                    else{
                        URL urldoc = null;
                        try {
                            urldoc = new URL(input);
                        } 
                        catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String url = new String("https://"+urldoc.getAuthority()+"/v2/swagger.json"); 
                        System.out.println(url);
                        Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read(url);
                        Map<String, Path> paths = swagger.getPaths(); 
                        // Create Root Pane.
                        VBox root = new VBox();
                        root.setPadding(new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Path> p : paths.entrySet()) {
                            Path path = p.getValue();
                            Map<HttpMethod, Operation> operations = path.getOperationMap();
                            for (java.util.Map.Entry<HttpMethod, Operation> o : operations.entrySet()) {
                                System.out.println("===");
                                System.out.println("PATH:" + p.getKey());
                                System.out.println("Http method:" + o.getKey());
                                System.out.println("Summary:" + o.getValue().getSummary());
                                System.out.println("Parameters number: " + o.getValue().getParameters().size());
                                for (Parameter parameter : o.getValue().getParameters()) {
                                    System.out.println(" - " + parameter.getName());
                                }
                                System.out.println("Responses:");
                                for (Map.Entry<String, Response> r : o.getValue().getResponses().entrySet()) {
                                    System.out.println(" - " + r.getKey() + ": " + r.getValue().getDescription());
                                }           
                                // Create First TitledPane.
                                TitledPane firstTitledPane = new TitledPane();
                                firstTitledPane.setText((o.getKey()).toString() + ":" + (p.getKey()).toString());

                                VBox content1 = new VBox();
                                content1.getChildren().add(new Label("Java Swing Tutorial"));
                                content1.getChildren().add(new Label("JavaFx Tutorial"));
                                content1.getChildren().add(new Label("Java IO Tutorial"));

                                firstTitledPane.setContent(content1);


                                root.getChildren().addAll(firstTitledPane);
                                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
                                stage.setScene(scene);
                                stage.show();

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json 0 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
=== PATH:/pet/{petId} Http method:GET Summary:Find pet by ID Parameters number: 1
 - petId Responses:
 - 200: successful operation
 - 400: Invalid ID supplied
 - 404: Pet not found Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
   Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0   
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)     
atcom.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:444)   at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:939)  at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:955)    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)  at GroupOfTitledPane$1.actionPerformed(GroupOfTitledPane.java:102)  at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)   at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)   at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)   at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)  at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: don't mix swing and fx except if you absolutely must! If that's the case, you must be very careful to fullful the threading rules of both, that is changes to the scenegraph only on the fx application thread (which you are violtaing here, as the error tells you) and changes to the swing hierarchy only on the EDT

Comment: @kleopatra is there is any way to use them both? Or is there is any way to create an Accordion using only swing? because I'm clearly a beginner in JavaFX and I don't know how to deal with it ?

Comment: _I'm clearly a beginner in JavaFX_ all the more reason to not mix :) either go the full way (starting with a basic tutorial and practice to get confident) or stick to swing (there are - rather oldish - toolkits that have a accordion, f.i. SwingX afair)